# PHP XDebug disable breaking on each request

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, break

I'm writing a webapplication that uses JS and PHP. Each time I refresh I get about 5 ajax calls to my php script. This is getting quite annoying using XDebug since it breaks on each of those request (without a breakpoint placed).

I thought this was a common problem but I can't seem to find anyting about it. Does anyone know how to disable breaking on each request?

EDIT: I'm using Wamp and Netbeans 7.0

- Rob

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the IDE the one that's stopping. In NetBeans, go to **Tool-> Options-> PHP-> Debugging** and uncheck **Stop at first line**.

[image: Screenshot from NetBeans 8.0]

<sub>(In earlier NetBeans versions the option was under *Tool-> Options-> PHP-> General*)</sub>

Comment: Update: It's Tool-> Options-> PHP-> Debugging in Netbeans 7.1

Answer (score 0):

From what i remember, xdebug adds something like `XDEBUG_SESS_ID=xxxxxxxx` to the url when debugging. if this is the case, then remove that from the url.

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely that you have some empty src="" tags or alike. You need to find out what (by checking your apache logs) which requests are made. Xdebug itself does not decide to make requests.

Comment: It doesn't make request. But it breaks on line 1 of each request I make.

Comment: Ah, I think many IDEs have a solution for this. There is often a "break at first line" option in them. You didn't mention which IDE you use so can't give you a direct pointer.

Comment: Added my IDE (Netbeans 7.0) to the question